# Expert System in Clips doesn't work

Tags: clips, expert-system

In my expert system user must check Developer and Price after he'll see notebook which is suitable for this parameters.

For example with this parameters (on screenshot) I must have result: Model: Noteebok1

[image: Screenshot]

But I don't see anything. Where is a problem or bug?

CLP File Code:

```
(defglobal ?*s* = 0)
(deftemplate Notebook
(slot pModel)
(slot pDeveloper)
(slot pPrice))
;*******************************************************************      
(deffunction QuestionOf(?TextQuestion $?variations)
(printout t ?TextQuestion)
(bind ?Answer (read))
(if (lexemep ?Answer)
then (bind ?Answer (lowcase ?Answer)))
(while (not (member ?Answer ?variations)) do
(printout t ?TextQuestion)
(bind ?Answer (read))
(if (lexemep ?Answer) 
then (bind ?Answer (lowcase ?Answer))))
?Answer)
;********************************************************************'
(defrule banner
(declare (salience 10))
=>(load-facts D:\fact.txt)
(printout t crlf crlf)
(printout t "Expert system. Nout search")
(printout t crlf crlf))
;******************************************************************'
(defrule QuestionDeveloper
(not (Developer ?))
=>(bind ?asssert(QuestionOf "Check Developer (a-HP,b-Samsung,c-Apple,d-IDontKnow)"  a b c d))
(if (eq ?asssert a)then (assert (Developer HP)))
(if (eq ?asssert b)then (assert (Developer Samsung)))
(if (eq ?asssert c)then (assert (Developer Apple)))
(if (eq ?asssert d)then (assert (Developer IDontKnow))))
;******************************************************************'
(defrule QuestionPrice
(not (Price ?))
=>(bind ?asssert(QuestionOf "Price?(a-300,b-400,c-500,d-IDontKnow)"  a b c d))
(if (eq ?asssert a)then (assert (Price 300)))
(if (eq ?asssert b)then (assert (Price 400)))
(if (eq ?asssert c)then (assert (Price 500)))
(if (eq ?asssert d)then (assert (Price IDontKnow))))
;******************************************************************'
(defrule Vyvod
(or (Developer ?xDeveloper)(Developer IDontKnow))
(or (Price ?xPrice)(Price IDontKnow))
(Notebook(pModel ?Model)(pDeveloper ?xDeveloper)(pPrice ?xPrice))
=>(bind ?*s*(+ ?*s* 1))
(printout t crlf "  " ?*s* ".  Model : " ?Model crlf))
;******************************************************************'
```

Fact.txt:

```
(Notebook(pModel Notebook1)(pDeveloper HP)(pPrice 500))
(Notebook(pModel Notebook2)(pDeveloper Samsung)(pPrice 400)) 
(Notebook(pModel Notebook3)(pDeveloper Apple)(pPrice 500))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facts from the file fact.txt are not being loaded. Check that the file is at the specified path and that you have read access.